# MySQL Error #1452 + Error creating foreign key

Tags: mysql

Im trying to link my tables now with foreign keys but with the following tables I have a few problems.

**My tables**

```
table users
- user_id INT(8) AUTO_INCREMENT //this is completly underlined
- username VARCHAR(150)
- password VARCHAR(50)
- auth_lvl VARCHAR(10) //this is "half underlined"
- ...

PRIMARY KEY: user_id
-------------------------------------------------
table groups
- group_id INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT
- group_name VARCHAR(30)
- group_desc VARCHAR(60)

PRIMARY KEY: group_id
-------------------------------------------------
table users_groups
- user_id INT(10)
- group_id INT(10)

PRIMARY KEY: user_id, group_id (command was: PRIMARY KEY(user_id, group_id)
INDEX: group_id (these are seperated)
INDEX: user_id (these are seperated)
```

**Now I wanted to create a foreign key with this:**

```
ALTER TABLE `users_groups` 
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) 
        REFERENCES `DB`.`users` (`user_id`) 
        ON DELETE CASCADE 
        ON UPDATE RESTRICT
```

The error was:

```
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
(`db`.<result 2 when explaining filename '#sql-censored'>, CONSTRAINT 
`#sql-censored` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`) 
ON DELETE CASCADE)
```

**My second foreign key I wanted to create:**

```
ALTER TABLE `users_groups` 
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (`group_id`) 
        REFERENCES `DB`.`groups` (`group_id`) 
        ON DELETE CASCADE 
        ON UPDATE RESTRICT
```

The error was:

```
Error creating foreign key on group_id (check data types)
```

What is the problem with these? I cannot find the fault :/

Comment: Do you already have data inside of these tables?

Comment: Yes, in all of the listed tables, I have at least a few rows

Answer (score 0):

The first one seems to indicate you have data in the table that does not satisfy the foreign key constraint.
The second one may be caused by the different data types INT(10) vs. INT(11).
Probably specifying INTEGER for all columns would solve this.

Comment: The second foreign key worked now, thanks! But the first one with the #1452 error still doesn't work. (again the #1452 error)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

I had some rows in `users_groups` where the user_id was an id of an user which isn't in the `users` table anymore.

After I deleted these values which aren't exisiting in `users` anymore, all worked!